# CDF at n of normal distribution to the nth power

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, lognormal-distribution

I'm working with an equation that includes a normally distributed investment return R.
I can find the Cumulative Distribution Function of R for the first period n=0.
However, how do I derive the CDF after n periods?

Specifically, if one dollar is invested, then at the end of n=0, the value is 1+R. After subsequent periods, the value is $V = (1+R)^n$.

What is the CDF of **V**?

The mean is $(1+\mu)^n$. However, the distribution skews right and becomes lognormal (if my understanding is correct). This fact is complicating the rest of the process for me.

I want R at each period to be independent and identically distributed.

Comment: If `R` is normally distributed, then regularly your investment is gone, because `R` can become smaller than 1. What happens then?

Comment: @Gijs I believe the convention is to use (1+R) for that reason, i.e. with 1+R, the distribution is the same but the compound effect on returns is increasing rather than decreasing as you are pointing out. Let me know if I should edit the question in a particular way to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really aware of convention in this area, but under your assumptions, the behaviour of $(1 + R) ^ n$ is pretty wild. If $R_i < -1$, then your investment becomes negative. I'm not sure if the resulting distribution wil converge.

Comment: Note that the mean definitely is not $(1+\mu)^n,$ assuming "$\mu$" refers to the mean of $R$.  Usually one models $1+R$ with a *lognormal* distribution, which gives $V$ a lognormal distribution, too.

Comment: @Gijs Thanks, I'm in finance, learning stats. R is usually modelled as Normal, from historical returns. The mean is generally somewhere between 0.00 and 0.15 (i.e. percentages), and standard deviations between 0.00 and 0.30. (There are some uncommon securities - leveraged funds come to mind - that may exceed these). Would it be useful to constrain R? If so, constrain mean and/or standard deviation, or values of R, or both?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, very helpful! In my experience, a security's $R$ is modeled as Normal - are you saying it would be more accurate/useful to model $1+R$ as lognormal (but keep R as Normal)? Can you point me toward resources dealing with this? Thanks again.

Comment: You can't simultaneously assume $1+R$ is lognormal and $R$ is normal.  However, when the standard deviation is small, the two models will be close except for the most extreme values--where the lognormal is much more obviously correct.  As far as resources go, I can't imagine any text or paper about finance that wouldn't discuss this.